# optional feature `uuid` required for type UUID of column #1 ("id")

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I'm trying to query a PostgreSQL database table using [sqlx](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx). But, the following error is shown

```
[rustc] [E] optional feature `uuid` required for type UUID of column #1 ("id")
```

My code snippet

```rust
use sqlx::{Pool, Postgres, postgres::PgRow, Row, FromRow};
use uuid::Uuid;

#[derive(FromRow)]
struct User {
    id: uuid::fmt::Hyphenated 
}

let result = sqlx::query_as!(User, "SELECT id FROM users")
    .fetch_one(pool)
    .await
    .expect("QUERY FAILED");
```

SQL

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Any idea how to resolve an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that I did not add a flag `"uuid"` in the `Cargo.toml` file

```
- sqlx = { version = "0.5", features = [ "runtime-actix-native-tls" , "postgres" ] }
+ sqlx = { version = "0.5", features = [ "runtime-actix-native-tls" , "postgres", "uuid" ] }
```

P.S.

Looks like I was using a different type of UUID.

I had the [Uuid](https://docs.rs/uuid/latest/uuid/) crate installed separately, but it required the Uuid from sqlx (eg [sxl::types::Uuid](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/types/struct.Uuid.html)).